# UItextfield error: Exceedingly strange

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

I have a textfield in a controller. Upon the first time loading, it looks great.
But say, for example, I send myself an SMS that appears as a banner at the top of the screen. I click that SMS, taking me to my messages app. Then I decide to go back to the app I'm creating. All of the sudden, the textfield only shows text every other letter I type (!?) and then text of the field is on the lower half of the textfield, not in the middle where I set it to be.

It is exceedingly strange. I have a lot of experience programming with UITextfield and never have I seen anything like this.

If it helps, here's some code from the controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.numAttempts=0;

    UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 0)];
    self.verificationTextField.leftView = paddingView;
    [self.verificationTextField setBackgroundColor:[ColorSuperclass returnSigningUpTextFieldBackgroundColor]];
    self.verificationTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.verificationTextField.text = nil;

    [self.verificationTextField layoutSubviews];
    [self.verificationTextField layoutIfNeeded];

    CGFloat buttonBarHeight=[buttonSuperclass returnBarButtonDimension];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NextButton"];
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonBarHeight, buttonBarHeight)]; //these constants can always be subject to tweaking in the superclass...
    [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(nextButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem * rightBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=rightBarButton;

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
}
```

Comment: Why do you call `layoutSubviews` of `verificationTextField`?

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug, just move view to bottom of hierarchy in .xib interface. It's an Apple IOS bug